Why sun revolve around the sun ? Why cant it just rotate ? ( gravitas attraction force makes it revolve , how?)
Why the revolution ?
How General relativity theory explains it

It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is.

Conservation of angular momentum.

The sun does not revolve around the sun.  The sun revolves around the barycenter of the solar system, which is the center of mass of the entire solar system.  Jupiter is massive enough that it shifts the center of mass of the solar system outside of what we think of as the body of the sun.
If it were to simply rotate about its own center, that would disagree with Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation.  That's not to say there's no way the universe could behave that way... it's just contrary to all of our observations.  All of our observations show that celestial bodies revolve around the barycenter of the solar system (or the planet/moon barycenter, in the case of moons)
One can show these things using general relativity, but there is no need.  The effect is measurable and predictable using Netwonian physics.
